# php ftp_put does not create file

Tags: php, ftp

I'm trying to upload an image file from my local PC to a remote server. The image comes from a simple html input (type=file) and file array contains these:

```
Array ( [name] => image42.jpg [type] => image/jpeg [tmp_name] => C:\wamp\tmp\phpBB52.tmp [error] => 0 [size] => 6051 )
```

As you can see, my local PC is using Windows. The code which tries to upload the image file is as follows:

```
$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server, $ftp_port);

$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_username, $ftp_password);

if(!ftp_chdir($conn_id, $folder_path))
{
    $create_folder = ftp_mkdir($conn_id, $folder_path);
    ftp_chmod($conn_id, 0777, $folder_path);
}
```

This perfectly connects to the server, even create a folder if it's not exist. Then when we get to the upload part,

```
ftp_pasv($conn_id, true);

// upload a file
$upload = ftp_put($conn_id, $new_dir, $file_dir, FTP_BINARY);
```

the variable `$upload` gets `false`.

`$file_dir` contains `C:\wamp\tmp\phpBB52.tmp` (i.e. file's `tmp_name`).

`$new_dir` contains the remote directory with image path: `img.example.com/data/images/blabla.jpg`

Also, the error returning is:

```
Warning: ftp_put() [<a href='function.ftp-put'>function.ftp-put</a>]: Could not create file. in C:\wamp\www\example\example.php on line 95
```

I have not found anything helpful neither on Google, nor StackOverflow. What could be the reason?

Comment: Check out your file permissions

Comment: Where? It's all 777 on remote server. Also the user I'm logged in on Windows have administrator permissions.

Comment: `bool ftp_put( resource $ftp_stream , string $remote_file , string $local_file , int $mode)` - are not mixing parameters? 2nd is remote file and 3rd is local file, but in your example you use locally uploaded as 2nd and 3rd as remote?

Comment: The order of the parameters are right. 2nd is remote, 3rd is local.

Comment: you say "$new_dir contains C:\wamp\tmp\phpBB52.tmp", but this is  uploaded file on the server, not remote target on FTP which you are trying to upload into, so for me they look still like swapped

Comment: Thanks for pointing this, I just wrote it wrong on the question, now it's correct.

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me. It could be the server's root directory is different from the FTP root directory.

Try logging into your FTP account with another program and check the root. For example, my FTP root is `/public_html/`, but the server is `/home/cms/public_html/`. So if my remote destination for my file was set to `/home/cms/public_html/images/82.jpg` just change it to `/public_html/images/82.jpg`.

Answer (score 0):

My script was trying to upload a file periodically to a FTP location(overwriting the previously uploaded file with the same name) and was working fine.

It started showing this error now and I did delete the file from the FTP location and uploaded it again using the script and the error is gone.

The file must have been locked by any other application in the FTP location preventing its overwriting or maybe it was corrupt.